# An element descriptor's .kind property must be either "method" or "field"

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I'm following the documentation for [`mobx-react-router`](https://github.com/alisd23/mobx-react-router) but upon attempting to run my application I get the following error in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: An element descriptor's .kind property must be either "method" or "field", but a decorator created an element descriptor with .kind "undefined"
    at _toElementDescriptor (app.js:49988)
    at _toElementFinisherExtras (app.js:49990)
    at _decorateElement (app.js:49980)
    at app.js:49976
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _decorateClass (app.js:49976)
    at _decorate (app.js:49958)
    at Module../src/App/UserStore.js (app.js:50012)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:1)
```

Here is how I intitialize:

```
const appContainer = document.getElementById('app');
if(appContainer) {
  const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory()
  const routingStore = new RouterStore();

  const stores = {
    users: userStore,
    routing: routingStore
  }

  const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, routingStore);

  ReactDOM.render(
    (
      <Provider {...stores}>
        <Router history={history}>
          < App />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    ),
  appContainer);
}
```

And this is how I use:

```
@inject('routing')
@inject('users')
@observer
class App extends Component { ...
```

My `UserStore`:

```
import { observable, action, computed } from "mobx"

class UserStore {
  @observable users = [];

  @action addUser = (user) => {
    this.users.push(user)
  }

  @computed get userCount () {
    return this.users.length
  }
}

const store = new UserStore();
export default store;
```

I've tried to Google for this error but it's returning no useful results. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using Babel 7 install support for decorators:

```
npm i -D\
  @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties\
  @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
```

Then enable it in your `.babelrc` or `webpack.config.js` file:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true}]
    ]
}
```

Note that the legacy mode is important (as is putting the decorators proposal first). Non-legacy mode is [WIP](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/pull/1732).

Reference: https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html

Answer (score 4):

While the accepted answer works, for anyone coming here from the same error message but a different context, this is likely because the decorator's signature changed as [the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) progressed.

Using `{ "legacy": true }` uses one method signature, while `{"decoratorsBeforeExport": true }` uses another. The two flags are incompatible.

You can inspect what's happening with the given example

```
function log() {
  console.log(arguments)
}
class Foo
  @log
  bar() {
    console.log('hello')
  }
}
new Foo().bar()
```

Using `{"decoratorsBeforeExport": true }` will yield

```
[Arguments] {
  '0': Object [Descriptor] {
    kind: 'method',
    key: 'bar',
    placement: 'prototype',
    descriptor: {
      value: [Function: bar],
      writable: true,
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: false
    }
  }
}
```

Where `{"legacy": true }` would give you

```
[Arguments] {
  '0': Foo {},
  '1': 'bar',
  '2': {
    value: [Function: bar],
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
  }
}
```

By *not* using the legacy semantics, writing a decorator is fairly simple. A decorator which returns its 0th argument is a no-op. You can also mutate before returning. Using the new semantics, you can describe a decorator as follows:

```
function log(obj) {
  console.log('I am called once, when the decorator is set')
  let fn = obj.descriptor.value
  obj.descriptor.value = function() {
    console.log('before invoke')
    fn()
    console.log('after invoke')
  }
  return obj
}
```

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer. Thanks for this. However, does this mean babel plugin completely off from latest spec? I see that the api is supposed to have 2 arguments value and context. Also, context object looks completely different!

Comment: The babel plugin was added before the proposal was mature. (You can read more about the proposal here -> https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) Since the spec changed, the babel plugin chose to support both old and new instead of forking. It supports the old signature and original version of the spec with `{ "legacy": true }`. It also supports the new signature and current version of the spec with `{"decoratorsBeforeExport": true }`.

Comment: Thanks so much. This should be indeed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the observable like so and it works (although not sure why):

```
import { observable, action, computed } from "mobx"

class UserStore {
  @observable users;

  constructor() {
    this.users = []
  }

  @action addUser = (user) => {
    this.users.push(user)
  }
}

const store = new UserStore();
export default store;
```

Comment: Can you please share you package.josn and .babelrc contents. Facing similar issue above didn't work.