# Is it possible to use decorators with create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have understood that since Babel doesn't support decorators out of the box (because it's in early stages of definition) create-react-app doesn't support it as well.

I know that you can eject the generated app and configure Babel to support them, but I don't want to do that.

Finally, libraries like MobX allow you to use decorator's behavior without actually using them, with the help of some utility functions like described at https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html

Is there something similar for React?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you need a couple of things,

Make sure you have [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) and [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra) installed so you can override webpack and babel configs

install [@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators)

and update your `config-overrides.js` file :

```
const { override, addBabelPlugin } = require("customize-cra");
const pluginProposalDecorators = require("@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators");

module.exports = override(  
  addBabelPlugin(pluginProposalDecorators)
);
```

Comment: For me, this failed because the plugin demanded that one of its options be set.  Supposedly you need either "decoratorsBeforeExport" or "legacy" (both boolean options) set, or something?  I dunno.  For the sake of others new to these tools, here's what ended up working:  I replaced the argument to override() with "addBabelPlugin([pluginProposalDecorators, {decoratorsBeforeExport: false}])" and then I referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628207/an-element-descriptors-kind-property-must-be-either-method-or-field/61542597#61542597 to learn to actually use the plugin without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use decorators with create-react-app by adding tsconfig.json file to the project that means enabling support for typescript.
You need to set `experimentalDecorators` to `true` in compiler options of tsconfig.json
Hope we are aware the .js and .tsx files can co-exist, so whichever file we want to use decorators we can convert to .tsx rest can remain .js files

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "noImplicitThis": false, 
        "experimentalDecorators": true,  //<---- 
        "types": ["cypress"]
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a combination of plugins

> **To enable config customization**

1. npm install [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra) --save-dev
2. npm install [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) --save-dev

> **To enable decorators**

3. npm install [@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators) --save-dev
4. `npm install reflect-metadata  --save-dev`
5. add `import 'reflect-metadata'` in index.js

> **Update configs**

6. remove `babel` config from package.json
7. create `config-overrides.js` file in project root
8. add code:

> ```
> const { addDecoratorsLegacy, override } = require('customize-cra')
>
> module.exports = override(addDecoratorsLegacy())
> ```

9. Change `scrips` section in `package.json`

> ```
> "scripts": {
>     "start": "react-app-rewired start",
>     "build": "react-app-rewired build",
>     "test": "react-app-rewired test",
>     "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
>   },
> ```